# Using grep or similar to match multiple lines

Tags: regex, perl

Say I have a file with the following text:

```
Line1
Cmd1
Cmd2
Cmd3
#
Line2
Cmd1
Cmd3
Cmd4
#
```

Where Line1 is a section, followed by a number of configs which may be different between sections, and then a # to separate each section.

I understand that I could use grep as following:

```
grep 'cmd2' file
```

to match cmd2 in the file. However, I only want to match cmd2 if it's in the Line1 section. Using -B isn't possible because there may be a different number of configs between sections.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this `awk` with custom `RS`:

```
awk -v RS=# -v ORS= '/Line1/ && /Cmd2/' file
Line1
Cmd1
Cmd2
Cmd3
```

Comment: Perfect! Anyway to print the current input filename with the output rather than just the output itself. I've found {print FILENAME} however this then just prints the filename.

Comment: Sure you can use: `awk -v RS=# -v ORS= '/Line1/ && /Cmd2/{print FILENAME "::" $0}' file`

Answer (score 0):

The `/s` flag lets you match across lines, so maybe you're looking for something like

```
if ($line =~ /line1.*?cmd2/is) {
    # do something here
}
```

I added `/i` to make the match case insensitive as well.